# 2d matrix to 3d stacked array in r

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a dataframe `data` in R of dim 120000 rows by 5 columns.

Each 300 lines is a frame measured at different time intervals (ie 400 frames)

**Action**

I tried using `array(data, c(300, 5, 400))`

**Expected**

Make this dataframe into a 3d array by splitting `data` every 300 lines and stack these 400 matrices behind each other.

**Actual**

Reads the values down along the first column of `data` and puts these into the first part of the array.

Comment: Did you try solving the problem by creating a *small* reproducible example?

Comment: Not as of yet, my major issue is to get the array to read the variables row wise instead of by column. I thought this would be a quick fix.

Comment: Usually, working with a small reproducible example helps identify the root of the problem. Look at `aperm`.

Comment: I've added some explanation (as you requested) and also put some benchmarks in there for fun :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option would be:

```
 m1 <- matrix(1:(300*400*5), nrow=300*400, ncol=5)
 lst <- lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)),(seq_len(nrow(m1))-1) %/%300 +1),
                         function(i) m1[i,])

 arr1 <- array(0, dim=c(300,5,400))
 for(i in 1:400){
 arr1[,,i] <- lst[[i]]
 }

m1[297:300,]
#     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
#[1,]  297 120297 240297 360297 480297
#[2,]  298 120298 240298 360298 480298
#[3,]  299 120299 240299 360299 480299
#[4,]  300 120300 240300 360300 480300

 tail(arr1[,,1],4)
 #      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
 #[297,]  297 120297 240297 360297 480297
 #[298,]  298 120298 240298 360298 480298
 #[299,]  299 120299 240299 360299 480299
 #[300,]  300 120300 240300 360300 480300
```

Or as suggested by @Ananda Mahto

```
library(abind)
arr2 <-  abind(lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)), 
           (seq_len(nrow(m1))-1) %/% 300 + 1), function(x) m1[x, ]), along = 3)
```

Comment: Slightly slower, but less manual work, would be `abind(lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)), (seq_len(nrow(m1))-1) %/% 300 + 1), function(x) m1[x, ]), along = 3)` (where `abind` is from the "abind" package). +1.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks I thought about `abind`, then I was in a mood to play with the `for` loop.  Also, because `aperm` based on your example was not getting the expected result.  I was using the wrong order like `list(300,5,400)` instead of `list(5,300,400)`. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach using `dim<-` and `aperm`:

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(sample(100, 12 * 5, TRUE), ncol = 5)
mat
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]   27   69   27   80   74
#  [2,]   38   39   39   11   70
#  [3,]   58   77    2   73   48
#  [4,]   91   50   39   42   87
#  [5,]   21   72   87   83   44
#  [6,]   90  100   35   65   25
#  [7,]   95   39   49   79    8
#  [8,]   67   78   60   56   10
#  [9,]   63   94   50   53   32
# [10,]    7   22   19   79   52
# [11,]   21   66   83    3   67
# [12,]   18   13   67   48   41
```

Slicing and dicing:

```
Sliced <- aperm(`dim<-`(t(mat), list(5, 3, 4)), c(2, 1, 3))

Sliced
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   27   69   27   80   74
# [2,]   38   39   39   11   70
# [3,]   58   77    2   73   48
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   91   50   39   42   87
# [2,]   21   72   87   83   44
# [3,]   90  100   35   65   25
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   95   39   49   79    8
# [2,]   67   78   60   56   10
# [3,]   63   94   50   53   32
# 
# , , 4
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    7   22   19   79   52
# [2,]   21   66   83    3   67
# [3,]   18   13   67   48   41
```

Adjust the numbers to match your data.

---

Breaking things apart, we get:

- `t(mat)`: transposes your matrix (so we now have 5 x 12).
- `dim<-(..., list(...))`: converts this to an array, in this case, 5 (row) x 3 (col) x 4 (third dimension).
- `aperm`: the result of the last step is by-row, so we need to convert it to by columns, so this is like a `t`, but with multiple dimensions involved.

---

These are also very efficient operations. Here's a comparison of this approach with @akrun's:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:(300*400*5), nrow=300*400, ncol=5)

am <- function() {
  aperm(`dim<-`(t(m1), list(5, 300, 400)), c(2, 1, 3))
}

ak <- function() {
  lst <- lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)),(seq_len(nrow(m1))-1) %/%300 +1),
                function(i) m1[i,])

  arr1 <- array(0, dim=c(300,5,400))
  for(i in 1:400){
    arr1[,,i] <- lst[[i]]
  }
  arr1
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(am(), ak(), times = 20)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#  am()  19.09133  27.63269  31.18292  67.12434 146.2673    20
#  ak() 496.11494 518.71223 550.02215 591.27266 699.9834    20
```

Comment: May I ask what's the time complexity of `aperm`?